# Visualizing decision trees in a random forest model

Tags: random-forest, graphviz, decision-tree

I have created a random forest model with a total of 56 estimators. I can visualize each estimator using as follows:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from sklearn.tree import plot_tree
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
 plot_tree(tr_classifier.estimators_[24], 
           feature_names=X.columns,
           class_names='IPSS-R', 
           filled=True, impurity=True, 
           rounded=True)
```

However, I want to visualize the best decision tree among the 56 estimators. How can I do that?